# why java multithread isnt speeding up graphic program

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, bufferedimage, zbuffer

i am trying to draw a triangle unsing multiple threads, each thread will draw an independent piece of the triangle. But its runs a lot slower than using just one thread. whats is the problem?

here is the code:

```
    (...)
int nCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[nCores];
    int width = box[1][0] - box[0][0];
    int incr = width / nCores;
    int x = box[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < nCores; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new TriFiller(x, x + incr, z - nx * incr
                * i));
        threads[i].start();
        x += incr;
    }
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < nCores; i++)    
            threads[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the runnable:

```
public class TriFiller implements Runnable {
    int xi, xf;
    double z;

    public TriFiller(int xi, int xf, double z) {
        super();
        this.xi = xi;
        this.xf = xf;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean inOut = false;
        double z0 = z;
        int rgbColor = shade.getRGB();
        BufferedImage image = wd.getImage();
        for (int i = xi; i < xf; i++) {
            for (int j = box[0][1]; j < box[1][1]; j++) {
                if (isOnSet(i, j, polyNormals, intBuffer)
                        && z < zBuffer[i][j] && z > zd) {
                    image.setRGB(i, j, rgbColor);
                    zBuffer[i][j] = z;
                    inOut = true;
                } else {
                    if (inOut) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                z += -ny;
            }
            z0 += -nx;
            z = z0;
            inOut = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because threads don't do magic and add overhead. Measure all the things if you want to know what the effect of threads is.

Comment: Are you able to provide a complete runnable example that demonstrates your problem...?

Comment: An interesting question is: why are you implementing z-buffering manually, when your graphics card already has an implementation of it that is much faster than your CPU could ever be?  OpenGL is quite capable of rendering to an off-screen buffer, and there are several different Java/OpenGL interface libraries for you to choose from.

Comment: Why use .join ()? .join () waits for the previous thread to finish. You could try using the executor class and .submit() to do parallel

Comment: Note this is just an exercise, I know that OpenGL is faster. I will follow your techique petro and see if performance is improved

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having trouble is, that swing painting doesn't work with multithreading. Read this extract from another [forum (jfree.org)](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30392):

"I think the reason that you are not seeing any performance improvement is that you are not introducing any parrallelism by spinning off another thread.

The way updating the screen works in Swing is essentially:

1) As soon as the component decides that it should be repainted on the screen, JComponent.repaint() is called. This results in an asynchronous repaint request being sent to the RepaintManager, which uses invokeLater() to queue a Runnable on the EDT.

2) When the Runnable executes, it invokes the RepaintManager, which invokes paintImmediately() on the Component. The component then sets the clip rectangle and calls paint() which ends up calling paintComponent() which you have overridden. Remember that the screen is locked and will remain locked until the component has entirely repainted the dirty rectangle.

There is no point in spinning off a thread to generate the image buffer, because the RepaintManager HAS TO block until the buffer is ready so it can finish updating the dirty rectangle before releasing the lock on the screen.

All the toolkits that swing supports (windows, linux, mac) are single threaded by design. It is not possible to concurrently update more than one region of the screen."

Comment: While I don't doubt your comments, the OP makes no mention of Swing in particular. I think you'll find almost all GUI frameworks have the same problem though ;)

Comment: first i use awt(dont know if is the same as Swing), then i just use threads to update the frame buffer which is kind of a matrix i guess(BufferedImage)